# How can I get HiDPI scaling on a 3440x1440p144Hz monitor with an M1 Pro?

Tags: display, resolution, apple-silicon

My setup is a 2021 MBP 16" connected to a 3440x1440p monitor at 144Hz via DisplayPort.

RDM.app/`/System/Library/Displays/Contents/Resources/Overrides/` was the solution on Intel/AMD macs but it doesn't work on Apple Silicon.

BetterDummy is the only workaround I could find but it doesn't support any refresh rate other than 60Hz.and also looks rather blurry compared to "native" HiDPI.

I cannot disable SIP as this is a work-provided machine. I do have root privileges though.

Comment: Can't you set the resolution and scaling in System Preferences > Displays > Display Settings? There's a "Show All Resolutions" checkbox that offers more HiDPI options.

Comment: No, there are only lower resolutions without HiDPI and those obviously look awful. As mentioned, I also used RDM.app which exposes all resolutions OSXII could use for the monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The evolution of BetterDummy [BetterDisplay](https://github.com/waydabber/BetterDisplay/) is capable of modifying monitor properties without dummies at full resolution (spacial and temporal).

Unfortunately though, it is proprietary, closed-source and paid.

Answer (score 0):

I recently made a simple command line tool that allows the use of all resolutions that macOS can use for your monitor in a similar way as RDM does but it also works on Apple silicon (at least for me) so if anyone is looking for something like this and is not afraid of using terminal then you can find it on my GitHub: [AllResTool](https://github.com/leszek-s/AllResTool).